# `OnUserPreferenceChanging` hang without background controls

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

In a [windows form application](https://github.com/mgaffigan/AppBarHangRepro/blob/master/Form1.cs) which changes the desktop layout as it closes, Windows Forms seems to hang while processing a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message.  This seems to happen for any `WM_SETTINGSCHANGE` message received between the start and end of application shutdown.

**Apart from adding an arbitrary delay, is there a way to avoid this hang?**

Apparent timeline of events:

1. On main thread, in closing the only Form, a change to the desktop layout is triggered (specifically due to removing an AppBar with `SHAppBarMessage(ABM_REMOVE, ...)`)
2. The main thread begins shutting down (disposing controls, form, etc...)
3. The ".NET System Events" thread receives `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` and Invokes to the main thread
4. Since the main thread has not shutdown, the [test at `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send:82`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Windows.Forms/System/Windows/Forms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs,82) succeeds
5. The ".Net System Events" thread enters a `WaitHandle`
6. The main thread, having had its main form closed, exits the message loop and `Main` returns
7. Hang

Call stacks at hang:

Main Thread (no .Net stack, only native)

```
win32u.dll!NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx()
combase.dll!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn(void * * ahEvent, unsigned long cEvents, unsigned long * lpdwSignaled) Line 2108
combase.dll!ClassicSTAThreadWaitForHandles(unsigned long dwFlags, unsigned long dwTimeout, unsigned long cHandles, void * * pHandles, unsigned long * pdwIndex) Line 54
combase.dll!CoWaitForMultipleHandles(unsigned long dwFlags, unsigned long dwTimeout, unsigned long cHandles, void * * pHandles, unsigned long * lpdwindex) Line 126
[Inline Frame] hostpolicy.dll!coreclr_t::shutdown(int *) Line 152
hostpolicy.dll!run_app_for_context(const hostpolicy_context_t & context, int argc, const wchar_t * * argv) Line 264
...snip...
```

.NET System Events thread

```
System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNoCheck(int millisecondsTimeout) Line 139
    at /_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/WaitHandle.cs(139)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WaitForWaitHandle(System.Threading.WaitHandle waitHandle) Line 3967
    at /_/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs(3967)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control caller, System.Delegate method, object[] args, bool synchronous) Line 7141
    at /_/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs(7141)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate method, object[] args) Line 6587
    at /_/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Control.cs(6587)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback d, object state) Line 88
    at /_/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs(88)
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SystemEventInvokeInfo.Invoke(bool checkFinalization, object[] args) Line 35
    at Microsoft.Win32\SystemEvents.cs(35)
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.RaiseEvent(bool checkFinalization, object key, object[] args) Line 850
    at Microsoft.Win32\SystemEvents.cs(850)
    locals:
        array[0] 
            ._delegate = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer.OnUserPreferenceChanging
            ._syncCtx = System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.WindowProc(nint hWnd, int msg, nint wParam, nint lParam) Line 961
    at Microsoft.Win32\SystemEvents.cs(961)
    locals:
        msg = 8218
        wParam = 0x2f
        lParam = 0
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll!Interop.User32.DispatchMessageW.____PInvoke|210_0(Interop.User32.MSG* msg)
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.WindowThreadProc() Line 1038
    at Microsoft.Win32\SystemEvents.cs(1038)
```

Notes:

- There are no controls being created on background threads ([Debugging Windows Forms Application Hangs During SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsui_team/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged) does not apply)
- Related: [WinForms application hang due to SystemEvents.OnUserPreferenceChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436981/winforms-application-hang-due-to-systemevents-onuserpreferencechanged-event)
- Issue opened: [Hang during exit if WM_SETTINGCHANGE is received](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/9721)
- At least one control is required on the form (to cause `SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanging` to be created via `VisualStyleRenderer..cctor`)
- [Repro with `SHAppBarMessage`](https://github.com/mgaffigan/AppBarHangRepro/blob/master/Form1.cs) and [memory dump](https://github.com/mgaffigan/AppBarHangRepro/blob/master/WinFormsSystemEventsHangRepro.dmp.zip)
- [Minimal repro with `SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, ...)`](https://github.com/mgaffigan/AppBarHangRepro/blob/minimal/Form1.cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [was a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/9721) in .Net from .Net 5 to .Net 7.0.11.  .Net Framework was unaffected.  To resolve, upgrade to a minimum of .Net 7.0.12 or use the `PostQuitMessage` hack below.

Use a custom `ApplicationContext` which ensures the `SystemEvents` thread is not currently hung before exiting:

```
Application.Run(new SystemEventsSafeAppContext(new Form1()));

internal class SystemEventsSafeAppContext : ApplicationContext
{
    public SystemEventsSafeAppContext(Form mainForm)
        : base(mainForm)
    {
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void PostQuitMessage(int nExitCode);

    protected override void OnMainFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var syncCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        SystemEvents.InvokeOnEventsThread(() =>
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            syncCtx.Post((_) =>
            {
                ExitThread();
            }, null);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT, the solution I gave is at best a dirty hack.  `QUIT`ing threads out from under winforms.  I'm hoping a proper solution shows up either here or from Microsoft support.