# GUI freezes, although the program continues to run in the background

Tags: vb.net

Background:
I have a windows forms app (in VB.Net) that controls and monitors the movements of a robotic arm. I have several threads (about 5-7) during runtime to do that. I synchronize shared variables among the threads using synclock. I have also 2 TCPIP connections. Unfortunately I can't provide any Code. The GUI has some labels that I update frequently with timers and few buttons to e.g. show a txt file that was written into during runtime or switch the state of a boolean variable.

Problem:
The app runs smoothly at the beginning for a certain amount of time, about 1h to 3h I would guess. After that, the GUI freezes but the program still runs correctly in the background. I know that, because the robot still moves and the logfiles that are created, provide the correct information.

A cautious gut feeling: Whenever button presses are performed on the form, the UI freezes faster than without a button press.

I would be grateful for any advice.

#### ---------- EDIT ----------

Thank you all for the responses. When the GUI freezes, I can observe in the debugger-thread window, that the Main Thread blocks on '... WaitHandle.WaitOne'. During my research on this topic, I came across the method of Vlad in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52721562 to identify any threads, that try to subsrcibe to the  'SystemEvents.OnUserPreferenceChanged'. I run this function in a timer every minute. There are some threads, that try to raise that event, but the GUI doesn't freeze immediately when these cases occur.
I would also like to mention, that I have a main TablelayoutPanel with some child objects which adjusts in size (depending on the screen size) when I start the app **after** the InitializeComponent() argument.

I have a Threadsafe class that I use in these threads to update any label, checkbox, etc. in text and color usually. Here is a sample code:

```
Public Shared Sub UpdateLabelInvoke(L As Label, txt As String)
        If L.InvokeRequired Then
            L.BeginInvoke(Sub() UpdateLabelInvoke(L, txt))
        Else
            L.Text = txt
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "*I can't provide any Code*" - this is going to make your question very difficult to help with. All you've provided is a high level description of symptoms you've observed, with nothing specific for anyone to help with. It's important to provide a [mcve] with relevant details, along with debugging info.

Comment: Timers?  What kind?

Comment: Don't use Application.DoEvents, if that's in the code. Also, how often are those label updates? There's no point updating them faster than the display refresh rate, if that's happening. You can save some work by only updating a label if its value has changed, in case you're unconditionally updating them.

Comment: "Unfortunately I can't provide any Code." - Why not? If you spent the time making a sample app that demonstrated the problem you'd be 90% the way to solving it yourself, and, if you still couldn't we'd solve it super fast. Without code we'll struggle like you have been.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the UI becomes frozen when something running on the UI is waiting for something else to happen on the UI.  This will freeze the UI.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim tsk As Task
        tsk = Task.Run(Sub()
                           Me.Invoke(Sub()
                                         Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString
                                     End Sub)
                       End Sub)
        tsk.Wait()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Button1.PerformClick()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is one fix,

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim tsk As Task
        tsk = Task.Run(Sub()
                           'use BeginInvoke instead
                           Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                              Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString
                                          End Sub)
                       End Sub)
        tsk.Wait()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Button1.PerformClick()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Another fix using Async / Await

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim tsk As Task
        tsk = Task.Run(Sub()
                           Me.Invoke(Sub()
                                         Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString
                                     End Sub)
                       End Sub)
        Await tsk
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Button1.PerformClick()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Without more from you it is all a guess.